# Make PNG files into a video using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have extracted all frames from an old video file, cleaned up video tape dropouts and film scratches frame by frame.

I now must reassemble the PNG files into a video .

I found this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg

and modified what I found there to:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -start_number 0 -i buggles%4d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out2.mp4
```

I have available only the first 500 frames @25 frames per second and am testing with that. It should yield a 20 second video

Instead I get a video of 41:35 in length that changes frames about every second and VLC reports 25 FPS.

Maybe I need to define that each image is on screen for only a single frame, but how?

Comment: Any chance you have a large number of duplicates of the input files somewhere in the input directory?

Comment: `-r 1/5` - this option seems strange.

Comment: Remove `-r 1/5` unless you want each image to last for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that removing the `-r 1/5` seems to work and reduces the length of the video.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/919230)

Comment: @music2myear Tekno Geekz can't critique or request clarification from the author, because he is the author who self-answered his own question.

Comment: (1) You say “removing the `-r 1/5` seems to work and reduces the length of the video.”  Does it reduce it to the 20 seconds you were expecting? (2) Please phrase this as a free-standing (self-sufficient) answer (giving credit to Gyan for suggesting it) rather than as an acknowledgement of a comment. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Oh, ah. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Yes it reduces it to the expected 2o seconds 1/25 sec per frame. The only issue I have now is that if the frames are numbered like

test01234.png
test01235.png
test01236.png
test01237.png
test11000.png
test11001.png
test11003.png

The output video goes only to test01234.png  and never moves on to test11000.png